# EF Core 6 randomly and rarely inserts multiple records

Tags: entity-framework-core, savechanges

On a simple form, with one textbox not readonly, I am getting multiple records generated which are identical except for the Id and UpdatedDate. I am using Entity Framework Core 6 and Razor Pages. This occurs only once every few hundred entries. Any thoughts?

I am entering the date like this:

```
Rate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

where Rate is the model I am binding to. I am saving changes with:

```
_context.MedBAmounts.Add(Rate); 
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

<td class="form-group" style="width:7%">
                <label asp-for="Rate.NewAmount" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Rate.NewAmount" id="newRate" class="form-control">
                    <option>164.90</option>
                    <option>230.80</option>
                    <option>329.70</option>
                    <option>428.60</option>
                    <option>527.50</option>
                    <option>560.50</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td class="form-group" style="width:6%">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-  mode="@Model.Mode" style="margin-top:15px; padding:5px;" />                        
            </td>
```

I am getting:
Two Ids, UpdateDate off by 1 second and same NewAmount. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IIdr.png)

Comment: Could be a double-click scenario. With action buttons including submit, it is advisable to use JS to disable the button on click and re-enable on completion (success or failure) or otherwise handle recurrent calls.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it was the issue. I will know for sure once the users get back in tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a common issue with web apps, especially once users start using it vs. your own testing. Some are "clicky" and either have a habit of multi-clicking, or instinctively click again if they click and don't get a visual feedback that something is happening within a second or two.